# A native call from java to C++ generates a pthread_mutex assertion error

Tags: java, c++, jvm, java-native-interface, pthreads

I'm encountering the following error at unpredictable times when calling a native method in java,

```
java: ../nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c:81: __pthread_mutex_cond_lock: Assertion `mutex->__data.__owner == 0' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

What we are trying to do is call a data extractor developed in c++ from Java code,

```
public int run() {
    while(this.TSbfr.canAdd() && this.hasMore())
        extractNext();
    return !hasMore() ? 1:0;
}
```

The native call is inside the **extractNext()** method and as you can see, we may have multiple calls iteratively.
When we run the jar file with **numactl --physcpubind=+1** to force the JVM to use one core, it works fine otherwise we get the pthred_mutex error, there is something weird here because we don't use any threads to run the **extract_next** method.

Our assumption is the following: if we have 2 native calls A and B, and A is taking some time, the JVM creates a second thread for the second call B that's why we get this error. We tried to use the java feature synchronized to lock the extract method but it didn't work.

I was wondering if anyone can give me some ideas about how to troubleshoot this error. Does anyone know of a common cause for this assertion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Our assumption is the following: if we have 2 native calls A and B, and A is taking some time, the JVM creates a second thread for the second call B`. This is not something the JVM will do automatically, unless you're running this on a forkjoin pool maybe (but it would depend on the code in `extractNext()`). Which version of Java/JVM are you using, and from which vendor?

Comment: The JVM will not just create another thread. The native code has a bug; without seeing that code, we can't really help you. Are you creating / using any mutexes in your native code?

Comment: @JornVernee We didn't use any threads to call native methods, the java version is 18.0.1.1 2022-04-22, and the vendor is Oracle Corporation

Comment: @JonathanS. We don't use any mutexes in the native code, I had the idea that maybe the native code has a bug but after executing the jar file with numactl and all works fine, I wasn't able to explain it

Comment: Are you calling this method from different Java threads, perhaps? Try logging the thread id?

Comment: Your application dumped core when it crashed. This means that there's a snapshot of the application state right as it crashed somewhere on your disk (potentially in the app's working directory, or in a central location if systemd is set up to capture core dumps). You can load this core dump in a debugger (i.e. GDB) and get a backtrace of the crash. This will tell you exactly where the app crashed. You could post this backtrace here by editing your question.

Comment: "*We didn't use any threads to call native methods*" -- of course you did.  All execution of Java code occurs in the context of a Java thread.  All execution of native code occurs in the context of a native thread.  And in most JVMs, these map one to the other.  You may not have created *additional* threads, but the JVM is multithreaded in any case.

Comment: But an assertion failure inside Glibc is really surprising.  I'm inclined to guess that something deeper is going on, such as the C++ code having been built against a different version of the C++ standard library than the one it is dynamically linking at run time.  Or some other, similar mismatch, but C++ standard libraries are a particularly rich source of version compatibility issues.

Comment: One way to check if there are multiple different C++ runtime libraries involved as @JohnBollinger noted is to run `ldd` against the native library for your code that you load into the JVM and see what C++ libraries it uses.  It should be something like `/usr/lib64/libstdc++so.6.0.25`.  If your code isn't linking against that C++ runtime library, but the JVM is, your configuration is broken and you're lucky it runs at all.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I ran ldd against the native library, but I didn't understand what to do after that, any help please, the following was the result: 
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0                   
libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6                                                                libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1                                                         libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6